# apt-get upgrade returns an error

Tags: upgrade

I had a serious issue before but finally got fixed, please refer to [Unmet dependencies error in ssh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041852/unmet-dependencies-error-in-ssh/1043201#1043201).

Now the system looks to be a healthy, fresh 14.04 trusty system. There is only one issue left.

After I ran `apt-get update`, no errors returned. When I run `apt-get upgrade`, it showed below first.

```
root@ubuntu:/# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  apt apt-utils aptitude base-passwd byobu command-not-found cpp cpp-4.6 dconf-gsettings-backend docbook-xml dpkg fontconfig fontconfig-config
  foomatic-db-compressed-ppds gcc-4.6-base gcc-4.6-base:i386 gettext-base ghostscript grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common install-info iputils-ping
  landscape-common language-pack-zh-hans language-pack-zh-hans-base language-pack-zh-hant language-pack-zh-hant-base lib32stdc++6 libasound2 libcairo2 libcupsimage2
  libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libfontconfig1 libgs9 libgs9-common libjpeg-progs libjpeg8 libjson0 liblocale-gettext-perl libmediainfo0 libnss3 libnss3-1d
  libpango1.0-0 libplymouth2 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libquadmath0 libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386 libsub-name-perl libtext-iconv-perl libuuid-perl libv4l-0 libxft2 libxml2
  linux-headers-generic linux-headers-server lsb-release man-db module-init-tools nvidia-common openjdk-6-jre-headless openprinting-ppds passwd perl perl-base
  perl-modules plymouth poppler-utils procps python-apport python-apt python-dbus python-debian python-keyring qemu-common sgml-base sgml-data ssh-import-id
  sysvinit-utils ttf-dejavu-core ttf-freefont ttf-kacst-one ttf-liberation ttf-unfonts-core ttf-wqy-microhei update-manager-core update-notifier-common upstart
  xml-core xz-utils
The following packages will be upgraded:
  app-install-data apt-xapian-index avahi-autoipd binutils ca-certificates cups-common doc-base dosfstools firefox-locale-zh-hans firefox-locale-zh-hant gnupg iproute
  iproute2 isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common jhead lib32gcc1 libglib2.0-data libjbig2dec0 libpam-runtime linux-firmware linux-libc-dev locales lshw ltrace mime-support
  multiarch-support mysql-common net-tools openjdk-6-jre-lib os-prober patch policykit-desktop-privileges python-apt-common python-chardet python-crypto
  python-httplib2 python-launchpadlib python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri python-oauth python-openssl python-pexpect python-pkg-resources python-problem-report
  python-serial python-simplejson python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-wadllib python-xapian python-xdg python-zope.interface rsync seabios sensible-utils
  shared-mime-info sudo tcpdump udev unzip usbutils uuid-runtime vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny w3m wget x11-common
70 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 93 not upgraded.
67 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/75.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 64.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

After answer `Y`, it went over a whole lot output, preparing, unpacking etc, but finally it ends up with below error.

```
Unpacking replacement libxrender1 ...
Preparing to replace gpgv 1.4.16-1ubuntu2 (using .../gpgv_1.4.16-1ubuntu2.4_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement gpgv ...
Processing triggers for doc-base ...
Processing 2 changed doc-base files...
Registering documents with scrollkeeper...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_204-5ubuntu20.28_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't have any errors if I install a normal software (e.g. `apt-get install openssh-client openssh-server` worked like a charm).

Additionally, the error is complaining about udev_204-5ubuntu20.28_amd64.deb, I checked on the packages.ubuntu.com, for 14.04 trusty, the package should be udev_204-5ubuntu20.26_amd64.deb (there is a slight different on the versioning).

Thanks and hopefully can point me to a right direction to fix this (apt-get upgrade).

Regards,
Denistone

Comment: Just noticed a reboot is required, I will reboot the box this afternoon and advise back here.   root@ubuntu:/var/run# ls -ltr reboo*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12 Jun  3 21:19 reboot-required.pkgs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 32 Jun  3 21:19 reboot-required
root@ubuntu:/var/run# more reboot-required.pkgs
libc6
libc6
root@ubuntu:/var/run#

Comment: after the reboot, found out the grub only has memtest.  Went through boot-repair and since then,  I had tried a few reboot without any further issue.  Now the system finally looks to be healthy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple workaround:

```
sudo apt-get clean        
sudo dpkg --clear-avail    
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Could you explain a bit more as what "dpkg --clear-avail" does to the system?  The manpage didn't help me too much --clear-avail
              Erase the existing information about what packages are available.

Comment: The error message I encountered didn't have anything relating to process available file,  it is actually complaining about processing a pkg file  /var/cache/apt/archives/udev_204-5ubuntu20.28_amd64.deb